# Bluetooth Detection Problems in Samsung Galaxy Tab using Android Bluetooth API

Tags: android, tabs, bluetooth, galaxy

I have a problem detecting zero class bluetooth devices with my Galaxy Tab using the Android Bluetooth API. It simply does not "see" some devices although I can detect them with my phone or computer. Has anyone run into this problem? I´m writing an app which depends on pairing with a device through bluetooth and some help in this regard would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Note:** This solution will only work with old Android OSs, due to it's need for access to the device logs.

Yes!  I have exactly the same problem, abeit on a Samsung Galaxy S, and LG Optimus One.  I wrote a class you can reuse to fix this, no idea if it will work on the Galaxy Tab, but you can try:

```
package com.yourpackagename;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.UUID;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.AsyncTask;

// This class exists due to a bug in the Broadcomm bluetooth stack, which is
// used by many Android smart-phone manufacturers (LG, Samsung HTC etc.).  That
// bug prevents discovery of ALL bluetooth devices that report their Class of Device (CoD)
// code as 0x00, which prevent many SPP (Serial Port Profile) devices from working.
// 
// See: http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#4hzE-Xyu5Wo/vendor/brcm/adaptation/dtun/dtunc_bz4/dtun_hcid.c&q=%22Device%20[%25s]%20class%20is%200x00%20-%20skip%20it.%22&sa=N&cd=1&ct=rc
// And: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4215398/bluetooth-device-not-discoverable
// And: http://www.reddit.com/r/Android/comments/hao6p/my_experience_with_htc_support_eu_anyone_has/
//
// How to use (from your Activity class):
// 
//  (new BluetoothClassZeroDiscoveryTask(this, new BluetoothDiscoveryCallback())).execute();
//
// Where BluetoothDiscoveryCallback is a class defined e.g. in your Activity.  The call method
// will be called after the discovery task completes, and is passed the complete list
// of paired bluetooth devices, including those that are undiscoverable due to the above bug.
//
//  private class BluetoothDiscoveryCallback implements Action<ArrayList<BluetoothDevice>>
//  {
//      public void call(ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> devices)
//      {
//          // Now you have the list of ALL available devices, 
//          // including those that report class 0x00.
//      }
//  }
//
//  // Java equivalent of the built-in Action from C#.
//  public interface Action<T>
//  {
//      void call(T target);
//  }
//
public class BluetoothClassZeroDiscoveryTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
{
    // This is the well-known ID for bluetooth serial port profile (SPP) devices.
    public static final UUID BluetoothSerialUuid = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");

    private Activity _parent;
    private boolean _discoveryComplete = false;
    private Action<ArrayList<BluetoothDevice>> _callback;
    private ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> _devices = new ArrayList<BluetoothDevice>();
    private Calendar _discoveryStartTime;
    private SimpleDateFormat _logDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.SSS");
    private BluetoothAdapter _adapter;
    private ProgressDialog _progressDialog;

    public BluetoothClassZeroDiscoveryTask(Activity parent, Action<ArrayList<BluetoothDevice>> callback)
    {
        _callback = callback;
        _parent = parent;
        _adapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

        IntentFilter foundFilter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
        _parent.registerReceiver(mReceiver, foundFilter);
        IntentFilter finishedFilter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED);
        _parent.registerReceiver(mReceiver, finishedFilter);

        // This task performs a scan for bluetooth devices, which 
        // takes ~ 12 seconds, so show an indeterminate progress bar.
        _progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(_parent, "", "Discovering bluetooth devices...", true);
    }

    // Kicks off bluetooth discovery.
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params)
    {
        _discoveryStartTime = Calendar.getInstance();
        _adapter.startDiscovery();

        while (!_discoveryComplete)
        {
            try
            {
                Thread.sleep(500);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e) { }
        }

        _adapter.cancelDiscovery();
        return null;
    }

    // Provide notification of results to client.
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result)
    {
        _progressDialog.dismiss();
        _parent.unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
        _callback.call(_devices);
    }

    // Handler for bluetooth discovery events.
    private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver()
    {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
        {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action))
            {
                BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);

                // If it's already paired, skip it, (we'll add it after the scan completes).
                if (device.getBondState() != BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDED)
                {
                    _devices.add(device);
                }
            }
            else if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED.equals(action))
            {
                // Add all already-paired devices to the list.
                for (BluetoothDevice device : _adapter.getBondedDevices())
                {
                    _devices.add(device);
                }

                // Trawl through the logs to find any devices that were skipped >:(
                try
                {
                    Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat -d -v time *:E");
                    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
                            new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

                    String line;
                    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(.{18}).*\\[(.+)\\] class is 0x00 - skip it.");
                    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
                    {
                        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
                        if (matcher.find())
                        {
                            // Found a blocked device, check if it was newly discovered.
                            // Android log timestamps don't contain the year!?
                            String logTimeStamp = Integer.toString(_discoveryStartTime.get(Calendar.YEAR)) + "-" + matcher.group(1);
                            Date logTime = null;
                            try
                            {
                                logTime = _logDateFormat.parse(logTimeStamp);
                            }
                            catch (ParseException e) { }

                            if (logTime != null)
                            {
                                if (logTime.after(_discoveryStartTime.getTime()))
                                {
                                    // Device was discovered during this scan,
                                    // now we want to get the name of the device.
                                    String deviceAddress = matcher.group(2);
                                    BluetoothDevice device = _adapter.getRemoteDevice(deviceAddress);

                                    // In order to get the name, we must attempt to connect to the device.
                                    // This will attempt to pair with the device, and will ask the user
                                    // for a PIN code if one is required.
                                    try
                                    {
                                        BluetoothSocket socket = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(BluetoothSerialUuid);
                                        socket.connect();
                                        socket.close();
                                        _devices.add(device);
                                    }
                                    catch (IOException e) { }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (IOException e) {}

                _discoveryComplete = true;
            }
        }
    };
}
```

See also:
http://zornsoftware.codenature.info/blog/pairing-spp-bluetooth-devices-with-android-phones.html

Comment: Thank you for your help, you really solved my problem. It may not be the ideal solution but it´s the only one I´ve come across. Do you know if this filtering of 0x00 class devices is part of the Android Bluetooth stack or if this is hardware related(an implementation of vendors like Samsung,LC etc.and thus device dependent)?

Comment: I believe the bluetooth stack is different between vendors, for example Samsung, LG, HTC all seem to use the Broadcom stack, but there are other bluetooth stacks out there if a vender choose to use different bluetooth hardware.  From what i've read, the Google Nexus phones do NOT filter 0x00.  (BTW please mark this as answered if your question is resolved - thanks.)

Comment: Is there a tick you can click on near the answer rating (to the left of the answer)?

Comment: Link is down. Anyone has the solution?